# Advantage of >> operator over / operator

Tags: java

What is the advantage of using >> operator over / operator? It was extensively used in the code I am maintaining. 
For eg, 
`int width = previousWidth >> 2;`

Comment: Unless otherwise noted, consider it an optimization. But also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168451/is-shifting-bits-faster-than-multiplying-and-dividing-in-java-net

Comment: A quarter of a century back in time, this really made a difference. Today it probably just means the person who wrote this code is either a programming veteran, learned from old books, or is trying to confuse you... ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want to shift a value by a certain number of bits, it's considerably simpler to understand. For example:

```
byte[] bits = new byte[4];
bits[0] = (byte) (value >> 24);
bits[1] = (byte) (value >> 16);
bits[2] = (byte) (value >> 8);
bits[3] = (byte) (value >> 0);
```

That's clearly shifting by different numbers of bits. Would you *really* want to express that in terms of division instead?

Now of course when what you really want is division, you should use the division operator for the sake of readability. Some people may use bitshifting for the sake of performance, but as ever, readability is more important than micro-optimization for most code. So in your case, if what's *actually* desired is for `width` to be `previousWidth` divided by 4, the code should *absolutely reflect that:

```
int width = previousWidth / 4;
```

I'd only use bitshifting for this after proving that the performance difference was significant.

Answer (score 0):

They are different operations:

- `>> 2` shifts a bit pattern two bits to the right (essentially dividing ***an integer*** by 2^2 = 4).
- `/ 2` divides the number by two (which could be implemented as `>> 1`).

Note that using `>> 1` to divide other numeric types by 2 is likely to give unexpected results.

If you mean "divide by two", type " / 2". People reading your code (including you, some time later) will thank you for not obscuring the meaning.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: I bet he mean `/ 2` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely nothing at all.  It would be a JVM optimisation to turn a division in to a bitshift.

If it's being done to a bitmask then fine, but if as in the above case it's what appears to be an awkward way of writing a mathematical operation then consider changing it as part of your maintenance (or just accept it as a bad idea but leave it alone).

Comment: nup..that doesn't happen!..test it for yourself

Answer (score 0):

As others already said, I suggest you always favor the more readable option over the optimization unless you

- definitely need that optimization
- know that it works by

  - knowing your compiler
  - knowing your JVM
  - having put performance measurements in place
  - considering statistic evaluations of those measurements (extrema, variance, first vs. later measurements, ...)