# Meaning of leading zero in integer literal

Tags: c

I'm studying (ANSI) C by [The C Programming Language (2nd Edition)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language).

This is a code snippet from **2.10 Assignment Operators and Expressions**:

```
1  /* bitcount() counts the number of 1-bits in its integer argument */
2  int bitcount(unsigned x)
3  {
4      int b;
5      for (b = 0; x != 0; x >>= 1)
6          if (x & 01)
7              b++;
8      return b;
9  }
```

I am confused why `x & 01` is written in line 6 rather than `x & 1` or `x & 0x1`? Is `0` before `1` necessary?

Comment: The section of the book may say "assignment operators" in the title, but the question has nothing to do with assignment operators, does it?

Comment: @David K Yes. Please help me change the title to fit the question, thanks. :-)

Comment: The new title looks good to me now!

Comment: It's used just for fast run code! `x & 01` or `x & 0x1` are fast than `x & 1` in running time. We can use `x /=2` instead `x >>=1` but this is lower running time than `x >>=1`. Also `x >>=01` is faster than `x >>=1`.

Comment: @KasiyA Why? Any reasons? :-)

Comment: @Kevin Dong Nai Jia:Ok read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168451/is-shifting-bits-faster-than-multiplying-and-dividing-in-java-net

Comment: @KasiyA The link you gave doesn't seem to say anything about the bitwise & operator, or the use of literal values with a leading zero.

Comment: @KasiyA that's not true.  shifting is faster than dividing but the way you express the literal at the language level has no impact on the bitwise operation done with the **exact same value** at run time

Comment: By preceding a constant with `0`, it indicates an octal constant (as others have mentioned).  It can _also_ affects the _type_.  Depending on value, a _decimal_ constant will be type `int`, `long` or `long long` and an _octal/hexadecimal_ constant will be `int`, `unsigned`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long` or `unsigned long long`.  With a value of 1, it make no difference though.  But had the value been `4294967295`, using `037777777777` would have likely been `unsigned long`, and not potentially `long long` with `4294967295`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 01 could also be written 1, or 0x1.

```
01  = Octal Constant  Base 8 (1 Decimal)
1   = Decimal Constant. Base 10
0x1 = Hexadecimal Constant. Base 16 (1 Decimal).
```

When the book was written, Base 8 (octal) was pervasive in existing computer programming.

Comment: Don't forget `0b01010101` - binary expression, this is also used.

Comment: @ST3, as an extension (not standard)

Answer (score 8):

A leading `0` makes a constant into an [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) (base 8) value.

In this case it's no different from `1` or `0x1` because they will all have the same binary representation of `000...001`.  People often use hex constants to distinguish that a value is being used as a [bitmask](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Masks.html) or other bitwise value today.  In the past, octal constants were more often used for the same purpose.

```
0x1  = hex constant = 1
0X1  = hex constant = 1
01   = octal contant = 1
1    = decimal constant = 1
1U   = unsigned decimal constant = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed "`01`" is distinct from `1` and `0x1` *in principle*.  "`01`" is encoded in octal.  Kernighan/Ritchie probably value the ease in which one can convert from octal to binary for this particular problem.