# How do I convert a C function that counts the number of ones in a 9-bit bitmask to Rust?

Tags: rust, bitmask

I have a `u16` which I use to hold a 9-bit bitmask and I want to find out how many `1`s it contains.

I [found](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Eam21/hakmemc.html) this [algorithm](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/hbaker/hakmem/hacks.html#ITEM167) that I have no clue how or why it works:

```
/* count number of 1's in 9-bit argument (Schroeppel) */
unsigned count_ones(unsigned36 a) {
  return ((a * 01001001001)     /* 4 adjacent copies */
             & 042104210421)    /* every 4th bit */
             % 15;              /* casting out 15.'s in hexadecimal */
}
```

How can I turn this into a Rust function? This is what I've tried but doesn't work:

```
fn main() {
    let a: u16 = 0b101_100_000;
    println!("Ones in {:b}: {}", a, num_of_ones(a));
}

fn num_of_ones(quantity: u16) -> u8 {
    (((quantity as u64 * 01_001_001_001) & 042_104_210_421) % 15) as u8
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A leading zero in C [denotes an octal literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23744027/155423). Rust octals start with `0o`, like the `0b` you already use:

```rust
(((quantity as u64 * 0o01_001_001_001) & 0o042_104_210_421) % 15) as u8
```

However, there's **no need for this** as it's built-in, such as [`u16::count_ones`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u16.html#method.count_ones):

```rust
println!("Ones in {:b}: {}", a, a.count_ones());
```

See also:

- [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40467995/155423)