# adding together the LSB and MSB to obtain a value

Tags: c#, byte, bit

I am reading data back from an imaging camera system, this camera detects age, gender etc, one of the values that comes back is the confidence value, this is 2 bytes, and is shown as the LSB and MSB, I have just tried converting these to integers and adding them together, but I don't get the value expected.

is this the correct way to get a value using the LSB and MSB, I have not used this before.

Thanks

Comment: just as an example, I have a value of 242 if I convert the LSB to an int, and 2 for the MSB, I am sure it is a simple equation, once its pointed out.

Comment: You can use bitwise operators: `(myByte & 1) + ((myByte & 128) >> 7)`, that's what they're for after all. You can also perform the whole calculation without addition if you'd like.

Answer (score 7):

Your value is going to be:

```
Value = LSB + (MSB << 8);
```

**Explanation:**

A byte can only store 0 - 255 different values, whereas an int (for this example) is 16 bits.

The MSB is the left hand^ side of the 16 bits, and as such needs to be shifted to the left side to change the bits used. You can then add the two values.

I would suggest looking up the shifting operators.

^ *based on endienness (Intel/Motorola)*

Comment: Why is an int 16 bits in this example? The inferred type of MSB << 8 is Int32.

Comment: this seems to work a treat, the maximum confidence reported back I 1000, and I am getting up to that value.. I do need to read up a little on this I think, as I need to understand exactly what it is doing. but thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that MSB and LSB are most/least significant byte (rather than bit or any other expansion of that acronym), the value can be obtained by MSB * 256 + LSB.

Comment: Shifting is sometimes faster than multiplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168451/is-shifting-bits-faster-than-multiplying-and-dividing-in-java-net

Comment: Yes, sometimes. It doesn't make the answer incorrect, however.

Comment: Yes, the jitter knows that as well.

Comment: this also works, so which is the most efficient way of doing it, or are they both as good as each other ?